# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when adding constraint

Tags: swift

My dashboard view was working fine until I tried to remove the storyboard from the project. I created a new branch using git and started to remove the storyboards and ran into this problem. Here is the basic setup of how I am getting to the dashboard screen.

```
// AppDelegate.swift 

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
window?.rootViewController = MainTabController()
```

```
// MainTabController
let dashboard = DashboardViewController()
let dashboardNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboard)
dashboardNavController.tabBarItem.title = "Dashboard"
viewControllers  = [dashboardNavController]
```

```
// DashboardViewController.swift

import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {
    var dashboardTitle: UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Defatul Dashboard Title"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.addSubview(dashboardTitle)

        dashboardTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true <-- Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    }
}
```

If I don't add a constraint the application runs fine, as soon as I add a constraint I get the error. Any idea as to why?

[image]

Comment: Your constraints look fine. Did you do this: _Click on the project’s name in the Project Navigator to access the options. In your target’s options, in General > Deployment Info. Change "Main" to "" ie make it be empty. Also can you look into the console and see if there is more detail about why it's crashing. Just search for 'constraint', usually there's good info there...

Comment: I do use the Main.storyboard to handle the register/login views. The AppDelegate file checks if the user has been authenticated. If they have it loads the MainTabController.

Comment: Are you creating a different label every time you reference `dashboardTitle`?  If that's what's happening, then the 2nd one has no relationship to `view`.

Comment: @PhillipMills No. I even tried to create the constraint `equalToConstant: 100` but the error persists.

Comment: @PhillipMills I guess I was. I didn't notice until overlooking how I defined the property. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new label each time you call `dashboardTitle`. You need to change `dashboardTitle` to:

```
lazy var dashboardTitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Defatul Dashboard Title"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
}()
```